# Org-Mode Babel, switches for code blocks: Can I set defaults?

Tags: emacs, org-mode, org-babel

In org mode, I can insert source in my org files. There are many header arguments, and I found how to set defaults. So I am down to only switches (here -n -r -l "..")

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp  -n -r -l ";(ref:%s)"
..
#+END_SRC
```

As I want to use these as site default: How can I set defaults for such switches?

Best in .emacs, but defaults valid for a file/buffer would be of help too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start with this hack

```
(defadvice org-babel-parse-src-block-match  (after org-babel-add-switches activate)
  "Add extra-sw to 3th element of the return value"
  (let ((extra-sw "-t -w 200"))
    (setq v (vconcat ad-return-value))
    (aset v 3 (concat (elt v 3) " " extra-sw))
    (setq ad-return-value (append v nil))))
```